# htaccess redirect all pages with ?= to /

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Someone managed to index a page with:

```
example.com/?ref=domain.com
```

The content of the page didn't change, but I don't want this url to get indexed.

Is there a way to redirect all /?whatever to / in htaccess?
I tried some redirect conditions, but ? is a special character and that's probably causing to fail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf and put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# query string is not empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
# request URI is / then redirect to / and strip out query string
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I found it to redirect internal pages to home. This appears to work better: # Redirect requests ?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*)?\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L] Do you see any issues using this instead?

Comment: @Roger: I am not sure which internal pages are not working. Can you please specify so that we can add an exception for those pages (if possible). However your proposed code will also work fine.